# Why am I getting ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[24,64,1024,1024] when my batch size is 1?

Tags: keras, out-of-memory, google-colaboratory, conv-neural-network

My model summary:

```
Total params: 932,225
Trainable params: 928,897
Non-trainable params: 3,328
```

I am using **loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd", and batch_size=1** for **binary** class semantic segmentation.

**24** is the total number of **1024x1024**x3 training images and **64** is the depth of the first conv layer.

***Note: I am using google colab gpu runtime.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing the **steps_per_epoch** to the model.fit and not **batch_size** which was not needed either in this case,

> ```
> H = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid),
>               steps_per_epoch=len(X_train)//BATCHSIZE, epochs=EPOCHS,
>               validation_steps=len(X_valid)//BATCHSIZE)
> ```

Replacing that **steps_per_epoch** with **batch_size** somehow solved my issue.

> ```
> H = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=BATCHSIZE,
>               epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))
> ```